# How requestAnimationFrame loop works?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm still learning javascript & Three.js and i'm having trouble understanding how the requestAnimationFrame function works. Could someone explain me how the following code works with simple words?

( you can check the full code [on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/) )

```
  // loop function
  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;  // convert time to seconds

    cube.rotation.x = time;
    cube.rotation.y = time;

    // render our scene
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

requestAnimationFrame() reaches out to the browser and asks it to execute a function before a repaint is done.

[requestAnimationFrame docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

The Code:

```
  function render(time) {    
    time *= 0.001;  // convert time to seconds

    cube.rotation.x = time;
    cube.rotation.y = time;

    // render our scene
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

- you set a time variable that will change in value on each call to render()
- you set the cubes rotation x and y values to the time variable
- you render the scene with the updated properties
- you call requestAnimationFrame passing in the render within the render function. This causes a loop that will continually repaint the cube on the screen with updated coordinates.
- You make a call to requestAnimationFrame passing in the render function once outside of the render function to do an initial rendering of the cube

Comment: "you set a time variable that will change in value on each call to render()" time is passed by rAF and is a timestamp (it generally is the time elapsed since the document is alive, like *performance.now()*)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! And thanks for the "time" value explanation, i think it's what didn't make sense to me!